# Disable hot edge to fire Auto-hide Ubuntu Dock

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, autohide

In Ubuntu 18.04 in **Settings** application I selected **Dock** from left panel and turned **Auto-hide the Dock** to **On**. Dock (the Launcher at the left site of monitor) is now hidden as expected.

There are two ways now to display hidden Dock:

- I can press <kbd>Super</kbd> key to display Dock, I like this.
- What I don't like is that Dock is automatically displayed when I move mouse to the far left site of monitor. How to disable this "hot" displaying of Dock when moving mouse to left edge of monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out in terminal execute:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide false
```

Additional notes:

- get current setting:

  ```
  gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide
  ```
- revert to default:

  ```
  gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide true
  ```
- there is also an option to install "gsettings" GUI application:

  ```
  sudo apt install dconf-editor
  ```

  and select above (and many more) option by using GUI.

Comment: How does that disable "hot-edge"? What you propose is identical to selecting "Autohide Dock" in settings, and would not prevent the dock from appearing when the mouse cursor reaches the edge.

Comment: There are just confusing names between end-user GUI and gsettings property names. In Settings app (turning "Auto-hide the Dock" to on) is actually "org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-fixed" setting by default set to true, setting above setting it turns it to false. But lets say "disable mouse hot-edge" is the setting from my answer "gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock autohide". Confusing names...

Comment: Indeed I see. Feel free to accept your own answer!